# How can I get the laravel join method without using foreach command?

Tags: laravel

How can I get the laravel join method without using foreach command? How can I solve it without using the Foreach command

{{$app->name}} I used to this type. But I'm constantly getting error.

Controller.php file content

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $show = Duty::where('duty_id', '=', $id)->count();

        if ($show!=0){
            $app = DB::table('users')
                ->join('duties', 'duties.appointed_user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->select('users.name', 'duties.*')
                ->get();
            $data = Duty::where('duty_id', '=', $id)->get();

            return view('duty.show', compact('data', 'app'));
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Sorun oluştu');
        }

    }
```

Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\personality\resources\views\duty\show.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

You have a list (collection) of users, not a single user. That is why you can't get just the `name` from it, because it doesn't know which one to get the name of. This problem has nothing to do with using the `join` method.

If you only expect to get one result from your query, you could change from `->get()` to `->first()`. This would allow you to call `{{$app->name}}` without breaking. But only do this if you expect a single result and use first.

If you expect more than one user, there is no way to display the names without looping in some way.

Answer (score 0):

That's what relationships are for. In that case you could do `User::with(:duties')`. Or in your case the other way around would probably work better `Duty::find($id)->with('user')`